# Why does this javascript code output 1 instead of 2?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var x = 1;
function fn() {
 console.log(x);
}
function show(f){
 var x = 2;
 f();
}
show(fn);
```

fn() function should have access to its outer execution context show(), which x is define as 2.

Comment: JavaScript has lexical scope, not dynamic scope. It considers the source code location, not the call stack.

Comment: Btw, your example is unnecessarily complicated. You could just have called `fn()` from within `show`, no need to pass it as an argument `f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `f` is bound with the context as it was when `f` was defined, that is, when `x = 1`. If you want `x = 2`, you need to *define* `fn` inside of the `show` function.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes, apologies for being correct.